# Android OpenGL texture bitmap no longer displays

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I have an Android app using OpenGL ES 1.0 to display a bitmap in a texture.
Recently it stopped working, at least in all the emulators (all Android versions)
and maybe on some users' devices. Nothing is displayed and the screen is blank.
Sometimes (maybe 1 random time out of 20) the texture is showing in blue color only,
but most of the time it's blank.

It works on my 2 physical devices.
I changed nothing in my code. Only updated the SDK.

Here is a sample testing code to demonstrate the problem.
Any help is welcome.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class OpenglBitmapTestActivity extends Activity {
  private GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;

  @Override
  public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature (Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow ().setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView (this);
    glSurfaceView.setRenderer (new GlRenderer (this));
    setContentView (glSurfaceView);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume () {
    super.onResume ();
    glSurfaceView.onResume ();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause () {
    super.onPause ();
    glSurfaceView.onPause ();
  }

  class GlRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private Square square;
    private Context context;

    public GlRenderer (Context context) {
      this.context = context;
      this.square = new Square ();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame (GL10 gl) {
      gl.glClear (GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
      gl.glLoadIdentity ();
      gl.glTranslatef (0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
      square.draw (gl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged (GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
      if (height == 0) {
        // Prevent divide by zero
        height = 1;
      }
      gl.glViewport (0, 0, width, height);
      gl.glMatrixMode (GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
      gl.glLoadIdentity ();
      GLU.gluPerspective (gl, 45.0f, (float) width / (float) height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
      gl.glMatrixMode (GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
      gl.glLoadIdentity ();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated (GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
      square.loadGLTexture (gl, this.context);
      gl.glEnable (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
      gl.glShadeModel (GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
      gl.glClearColor (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
      gl.glClearDepthf (1.0f);
      gl.glEnable (GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
      gl.glDepthFunc (GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
      gl.glHint (GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
    }
  }


  public class Square {

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private float vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
    private float texture[] = {
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    private int[] textures = new int[1];

    public Square () {
      ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect (vertices.length * 4);
      byteBuffer.order (ByteOrder.nativeOrder ());
      vertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer ();
      vertexBuffer.put (vertices);
      vertexBuffer.position (0);
      byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect (texture.length * 4);
      byteBuffer.order (ByteOrder.nativeOrder ());
      textureBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer ();
      textureBuffer.put (texture);
      textureBuffer.position (0);
    }

    public void loadGLTexture (GL10 gl, Context context) {
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource (context.getResources (), R.drawable.bitmap);
      gl.glGenTextures (1, textures, 0);
      gl.glBindTexture (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
      gl.glTexParameterf (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
      gl.glTexParameterf (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
      GLUtils.texImage2D (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
      bitmap.recycle ();
    }

    public void draw (GL10 gl) {
      gl.glBindTexture (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
      gl.glEnableClientState (GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
      gl.glEnableClientState (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
      gl.glFrontFace (GL10.GL_CW);
      gl.glVertexPointer (3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
      gl.glTexCoordPointer (2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
      gl.glDrawArrays (GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);
      gl.glDisableClientState (GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
      gl.glDisableClientState (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which SDK? What was the previous version? What is the new version?

Comment: Latest version.